# How to initialize the end size of image after affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry, image-processing, python

How to initialize the end size of image after affine transformation. How can i calculate them?

````
from PIL import Image 
import math 
 
img = Image.open('image.png') 
img.convert('RGB') 
result = Image.new('RGB', (87, 87)) # and here I want to know the dimensions in advance, because now I have entered them myself
width, height = img.size 
a = 60 * (math.pi / 180) 
xmin = width 
xmax = 0 
ymin = height 
ymax = 0 
for i in range(0, width): 
    for j in range(0, height): 
        colors = img.getpixel((i, j)) 
        x = int(i * math.cos(a) + j * math.sin(a)) 
        y = -int(i * math.sin(a) - j * math.cos(a) - 54) 
        result.putpixel((x, y), colors) 
result.show()
```
````

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Why can't you just take `min` and `max` of only the corner pixels' resulting $x$ and $y$? @RoyalGoose. Also consider using result of `img.load()` and pre-compute `math.sin(a)` and `math.cos(a)` to save computing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, we get only corner pixels transformed coordinates.

```
max_dim=tuple(max(
 (int(i * math.cos(a) + j * math.sin(a)),
 -int(i * math.sin(a) - j * math.cos(a) - 54))[k]
 for i in range(0, width, width-1)
    for j in range(0, height,height-1)
) for k in [0,1])
result = Image.new('RGB', max_dim)
```

Comment: why you use ... .cos(a) - 54, where did this number come from?

Comment: Dunno, it's from your code. I only did get vertices of the rectangle in a loop.

Comment: omg, thx, i markered as solution

Comment: I'm glad if it really helps. Thanks.